# Python multiprocessing pool force distribution of process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

This question comes as a result of trying to combine logging with a multiprocessing pool. Under Linux there is nothing to do; the module containing my pool worker method inherits the main app logger properties. Under Windows I have to initialize the logger in each process, which I do by running pool.map_async with the initializer method. The problem is that the method runs so quickly that it gets executed more than once in some processes and not at all in others. I can get it to work properly if I add a short time delay to the method but this seems inelegant.

Is there a way to force the pool to distribute the processes evenly?

(some background: http://plumberjack.blogspot.de/2010/09/using-logging-with-multiprocessing.html)

The code is as follows, I can't really post the whole module ;-)
The call is this:

```
# Set up logger on Windows platforms
if os.name == 'nt':
    _ = pool.map_async(ml.worker_configurer,
                       [self._q for _ in range(mp.cpu_count())])
```

The function ml.worker_configurer is this:

```
def worker_configurer(queue, delay=True):
    h = QueueHandler(queue)
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(h)
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    if delay:
        import time
        time.sleep(1.0)
    return
```

New worker configurer

```
def worker_configurer2(queue):
    root = logging.getLogger()
    if not root.handlers:
        h = QueueHandler(queue)
        root.addHandler(h)
        root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: `Pool` is really useful for quick parallelization, but not really good if you want fine-grained control of your processes.

Comment: I'm using pool for performance. I can re-use it for several stages of my calculation without the overhead of starting the processes, especially on Windows.

Comment: I see. Your best bet is to move logger configuration inside of each your worker functions. For example, define a function `get_logger`, which first checks for a logger and configures one if necessary before returning the configured logger object. This logger can be a global, since the processes have separate environments.

Comment: I originally had the logger configuration as the first part of my worker function, but as the function was called several times per worker I ended up with ever more logger handlers and duplicate, triplicate...etc messages! I guess the trick is to first check to see if there is a logger configured, which I shall now have to google...

Comment: Thanks @JoelCornett That did the trick. I added my new worker_configurer to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65092/discussion-between-paul-wells-and-joel-cornett).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
sub_logger = None

def get_logger():
    global sub_logger
    if sub_logger is None:
        # configure logger

    return sub_logger

def worker1():
    logger = get_logger()
    # DO WORK

def worker2():
    logger = get_logger()
    # DO WORK

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
result = pool.map_async(worker1, some_data)
result.get()
result = pool.map_async(worker2, some_data)
result.get()
# and so on and so forth
```

Because each process has its own memory space (and thus it's own set of global variables), you can set the initial global logger to `None` and only configure the logger if it has not been previously configured.

Comment: Hmm, I can see how that works but I already implemented a configurer that checks the existing logger for handlers, since it's the duplication of the handler that causes the problem. Do you see any drawbacks with my solution? Is the global approach a better way?